# browsersync not working on offline

Tags: npm, browser-sync

I got an weird issue. BroswerSync works fine when i am on online(connected by wimax) but not working or launching browser when I on offline. Few days back, same issue happened with livereload. What might be the problem?

Here is simple code on `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        }
    })
});
```

when i run gulp command showing-

```
$ gulp browser-sync
[23:25:12] Using gulpfile e:\myapps\gulp-browsersync\gulpfile.js
[23:25:12] Starting 'browser-sync'...
[23:25:13] Finished 'browser-sync' after 119 ms
```

and stopped..

Comment: Is there a browser-sync error that you could provide ? Couldn't you be loading some assets via a cdn in your code ?

Comment: no error showing... just nothing happen.. I updated my question... please help @topheman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Case I just change

```
proxy: 'localhost:80'
```

to

```
proxy: '127.0.0.98:80'
```

and its start working..

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something here, but have you tried setting browserSync options to offline : true ? 
If not, this may very well be the problem.

Link : http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-online